# How can I select first <p> element inside <article> element?

Tags: html, html-select

But here `<article>` element has other elements before first `<p>` element I tried  `section article p:first-child` and `section article>p:first-child`I think it's wrong so please tell me what is the answer

```html
<section id="news">
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1><a href="item.html">Quisque a dapibus magna, non scelerisque</a></h1>
    </header>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/business/" alt="">
    <p>Etiam massa.</p>
    <p>Dut venenatis.</p>
    <p>Mauroncus lorem eget.</p>
    <footer>
      <span class="author">Dominic Woods</span>
      <span class="tags"><a href="index.html">#politics</a> <a href="index.html">#economy</a></span>
      <span class="date">15m</span>
      <a class="comments" href="item.html#comments">5</a>
    </footer>
  </article>

  <article>
    ......
  </article>

  <article>
    ......
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) pseudo class should do exactly what you want:

```css
section article>p:first-of-type {
 outline: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<section id="news">
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1><a href="item.html">Quisque a dapibus magna, non scelerisque</a></h1>
    </header>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/business/" alt="">
    <p>Etiam massa.</p>
    <p>Dut venenatis.</p>
    <p>Mauroncus lorem eget.</p>
    <footer>
      <span class="author">Dominic Woods</span>
      <span class="tags"><a href="index.html">#politics</a> <a href="index.html">#economy</a></span>
      <span class="date">15m</span>
      <a class="comments" href="item.html#comments">5</a>
    </footer>
  </article>

  <article>
    ......
  </article>

  <article>
    ......
  </article>
</section>
```

While `:first-child` only matches when the element is truly the first child of its parent element, `:first-of-type` will match the first occurrence even if there are other elements beforehand.

Comment: @ADITYA regarding your edit: I had to reject it because it overlapped with another edit of mine that already fixed the typo. But you're right, `::` marks pseudo elements, while `:` marks pseudo classes. Browser implementations are actually quite forgiving in accepting `:before` and `:after` for historic reasons, but the other way round, at least Chrome won't accept `::first-of-type`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with `article p:first-of-type`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```css
section article > p:first-of-type { background: #121212; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<section id="news">
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1><a href="item.html">Quisque a dapibus magna, non scelerisque</a></h1>
    </header>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/business/" alt="">
    <p>Etiam massa.</p>
    <p>Dut venenatis.</p>
    <p>Mauroncus lorem eget.</p>
    <footer>
      <span class="author">Dominic Woods</span>
      <span class="tags"><a href="index.html">#politics</a> <a href="index.html">#economy</a></span>
      <span class="date">15m</span>
      <a class="comments" href="item.html#comments">5</a>
    </footer>
  </article>

  <article>
    ......
  </article>

  <article>
    ......
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To select like belows and changes the properties of p tag:

```
section article > p:first-of-type {
 text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the answers that have already been provided.

Comment: actually, this is the solution that I haven't seen tha someone already posted! apologies for that!